# Is there a way to reset all configuration in MySQL?

Tags: mysql, laravel, docker

I need your help again.

Is there a way to reset all configuration in MySQL?

Here's what happened. I previously have a project installed and this time I'm setting up a new one.

In this new project, I wanted to set it up with my a new database, new username I created and password. However, when I reached the point where I had to execute `php artisan migrate`, it keeps throwing me an error saying `PDOException::("SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] No such file or directory")`

If not that error, it's throwing `connection refused` instead.

Note: I'm using laradock.

Now, I'm at the point where I'd just rather reset the whole MySQL because I'm thinking it's conflicting with my previous configuration with my previous project.

As I searched online, I've tried the following:
1. Restarted server
2. Changed db_host from 127.0.0.1 to localhost and vice-versa
3. Added the project's directory to the dev environment setting
4. Docker-compose down and then up again
5. Even uninstalled and reinstalled docker itself

```
DB_CONNECTION=mysql
DB_HOST=localhost
DB_PORT=3306
DB_DATABASE=newdbname
DB_USERNAME=newusername
DB_PASSWORD=newpassword!
```

All I want is to be able to execute `php artisan migrate` using the new credentials I set.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you really do not need any old data in database, you can just delete them & reset up a container:

```
# stop mysql service
docker-compose stop mysql

# delete old mysql database
rm -rf ~/.laradock/data/mysql

# resetup mysql container
docker-compose up -d nginx mysql
```

You can get the mysql database location according to `docker-compose.yml` & `env-example`:

**docker-compose.yml:**

```
volumes:
    - ${DATA_PATH_HOST}/mysql:/var/lib/mysql
```

**env-example:**

```
DATA_PATH_HOST=~/.laradock/data
```

Comment: I can't seem to find the docker-compose.yml in my project. Also, inside the env-example file, there's no line for DATA_PATH_HOST

Comment: Sorry, I actually found the docker-compose.yml file.

```
        - ${DATA_PATH_HOST}/mysql:/var/lib/mysql
        - ${MYSQL_ENTRYPOINT_INITDB}:/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d
```

Comment: Yes, just delete `~/.laradock/data/mysql` then restart the mysql service to reset your database. Another volume just for entrypoint script, not related to database.

Comment: Thank you @atline, I was able to reset my database now.